# cross-compilation with GCC fails under CYGWIN when <iostream> is included

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, cygwin, cross-compiling

I've built the cross toolchain for Linux under CYGWIN environment using the article at https://preshing.com/20141119/how-to-build-a-gcc-cross-compiler/ as a source.

Compilation and installation finished with success.

Used components are:

- binutils-2.35
- cloog-0.18.1
- gcc-10.2.0
- glibc-2.32
- gmp-6.1.2
- isl-0.20
- linux-5.9.3
- mpc-1.1.0
- mpfr-4.0.2

GCC is configured as:

```
$ x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-g++ --verbose
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/opt/cross/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/libexec/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux- 
gnu/10.2.0/lto-wrapper.exe
Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../gcc-10.2.0/configure --prefix=/opt/cross/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu -- 
target=x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu --enable-languages=c,c++ --disable-nls --disable-multilib --with- 
headers=/opt/cross/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/include/linux
Thread model: posix
Supported LTO compression algorithms: zlib
gcc version 10.2.0 (GCC)
```

But when I'm trying to compile the simple Hello World application that includes  I'm getting a lot of different errors:

```bash
$ x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-g++ main.cpp
In file included from /opt/cross/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/include/c++/10.2.0/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bits/gthr-default.h:35,
                 from /opt/cross/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/include/c++/10.2.0/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bits/gthr.h:148,
                 from /opt/cross/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/include/c++/10.2.0/ext/atomicity.h:35,
                 from /opt/cross/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/include/c++/10.2.0/bits/ios_base.h:39,
                 from /opt/cross/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/include/c++/10.2.0/ios:42,
                 from /opt/cross/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/include/c++/10.2.0/ostream:38,
                 from /opt/cross/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/include/c++/10.2.0/iostream:39,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/opt/cross/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/include/pthread.h:240:34: error: 'clockid_t' has not been declared
  240 |                                  clockid_t __clockid,
      |                                  ^~~~~~~~~
/opt/cross/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/include/pthread.h:375:12: error: 'cpu_set_t' does not name a type
  375 |      const cpu_set_t *__cpuset)
      |            ^~~~~~~~~
/opt/cross/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/include/pthread.h:382:6: error: 'cpu_set_t' has not been declared
  382 |      cpu_set_t *__cpuset)
      |      ^~~~~~~~~
/opt/cross/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/include/pthread.h:466:14: error: 'cpu_set_t' does not name a type
  466 |        const cpu_set_t *__cpuset)
      |              ^~~~~~~~~
/opt/cross/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/include/pthread.h:471:8: error: 'cpu_set_t' has not been declared
  471 |        cpu_set_t *__cpuset)
      |        ^~~~~~~~~
/opt/cross/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/include/pthread.h:765:9: error: 'clockid_t' has not been declared
  765 |         clockid_t __clockid,
      |         ^~~~~~~~~
/opt/cross/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/include/pthread.h:911:12: error: 'clockid_t' has not been declared
  911 |            clockid_t __clockid,
      |            ^~~~~~~~~
/opt/cross/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/include/pthread.h:933:12: error: 'clockid_t' has not been declared
  933 |            clockid_t __clockid,
      |            ^~~~~~~~~
In file included from /opt/cross/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/include/c++/10.2.0/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bits/gthr.h:148,
                 from /opt/cross/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/include/c++/10.2.0/ext/atomicity.h:35,
                 from /opt/cross/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/include/c++/10.2.0/bits/ios_base.h:39,
                 from /opt/cross/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/include/c++/10.2.0/ios:42,
                 from /opt/cross/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/include/c++/10.2.0/ostream:38,
                 from /opt/cross/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/include/c++/10.2.0/iostream:39,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/opt/cross/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/include/c++/10.2.0/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bits/gthr-default.h:114:1: error: 'sched_yield' was not declared in this scope; did you mean 'pthread_yield'?
  114 | __gthrw(sched_yield)
      | ^~~~~~~
/opt/cross/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/include/c++/10.2.0/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bits/gthr-default.h:114:1: error: 'sched_yield' was not declared in this scope; did you mean 'pthread_yield'?
  114 | __gthrw(sched_yield)
      | ^~~~~~~
/opt/cross/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/include/c++/10.2.0/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bits/gthr-default.h: In function 'int __gthread_yield()':
/opt/cross/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/include/c++/10.2.0/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bits/gthr-default.h:693:33: error: '__gthrw_sched_yield' cannot be used as a function
  693 |   return __gthrw_(sched_yield) ();
      |                                 ^
In file included from /opt/cross/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/include/sys/select.h:37,
                 from /opt/cross/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/include/sys/types.h:179,
                 from /opt/cross/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/include/stdlib.h:394,
                 from /opt/cross/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/include/c++/10.2.0/cstdlib:75,
                 from /opt/cross/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/include/c++/10.2.0/ext/string_conversions.h:41,
                 from /opt/cross/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/include/c++/10.2.0/bits/basic_string.h:6535,
                 from /opt/cross/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/include/c++/10.2.0/string:55,
                 from /opt/cross/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/include/c++/10.2.0/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /opt/cross/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/include/c++/10.2.0/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /opt/cross/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/include/c++/10.2.0/ios:42,
                 from /opt/cross/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/include/c++/10.2.0/ostream:38,
                 from /opt/cross/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/include/c++/10.2.0/iostream:39,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/opt/cross/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/include/bits/types/struct_timeval.h: At global scope:
/opt/cross/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/include/bits/types/struct_timeval.h:8:8: error: redefinition of 'struct timeval'
    8 | struct timeval
      |        ^~~~~~~
In file included from /opt/cross/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/include/pthread.h:23,
                 from /opt/cross/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/include/c++/10.2.0/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bits/gthr-default.h:35,
                 from /opt/cross/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/include/c++/10.2.0/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bits/gthr.h:148,
                 from /opt/cross/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/include/c++/10.2.0/ext/atomicity.h:35,
                 from /opt/cross/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/include/c++/10.2.0/bits/ios_base.h:39,
                 from /opt/cross/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/include/c++/10.2.0/ios:42,
                 from /opt/cross/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/include/c++/10.2.0/ostream:38,
                 from /opt/cross/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/include/c++/10.2.0/iostream:39,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/opt/cross/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/sys-include/time.h:16:8: note: previous definition of 'struct timeval'
   16 | struct timeval {
      |        ^~~~~~~
In file included from /opt/cross/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/include/c++/10.2.0/ext/string_conversions.h:44,
                 from /opt/cross/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/include/c++/10.2.0/bits/basic_string.h:6535,
                 from /opt/cross/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/include/c++/10.2.0/string:55,
                 from /opt/cross/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/include/c++/10.2.0/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /opt/cross/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/include/c++/10.2.0/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /opt/cross/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/include/c++/10.2.0/ios:42,
                 from /opt/cross/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/include/c++/10.2.0/ostream:38,
                 from /opt/cross/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/include/c++/10.2.0/iostream:39,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/opt/cross/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/include/c++/10.2.0/ext/string_conversions.h: In constructor '__gnu_cxx::__stoa(_TRet (*)(const _CharT*, _CharT**, _Base ...), const char*, const _CharT*, std::size_t*, _Base ...)::_Save_errno::_Save_errno()':
/opt/cross/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/include/c++/10.2.0/ext/string_conversions.h:63:27: error: 'errno' was not declared in this scope
   63 |  _Save_errno() : _M_errno(errno) { errno = 0; }
      |                           ^~~~~
In file included from /opt/cross/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/include/c++/10.2.0/bits/basic_string.h:6535,
                 from /opt/cross/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/include/c++/10.2.0/string:55,
                 from /opt/cross/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/include/c++/10.2.0/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /opt/cross/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/include/c++/10.2.0/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /opt/cross/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/include/c++/10.2.0/ios:42,
                 from /opt/cross/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/include/c++/10.2.0/ostream:38,
                 from /opt/cross/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/include/c++/10.2.0/iostream:39,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/opt/cross/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/include/c++/10.2.0/ext/string_conversions.h:45:1: note: 'errno' is defined in header '<cerrno>'; did you forget to '#include <cerrno>'?
   44 | #include <cerrno>
  +++ |+#include <cerrno>
   45 |
In file included from /opt/cross/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/include/c++/10.2.0/ext/string_conversions.h:44,
                 from /opt/cross/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/include/c++/10.2.0/bits/basic_string.h:6535,
                 from /opt/cross/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/include/c++/10.2.0/string:55,
                 from /opt/cross/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/include/c++/10.2.0/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /opt/cross/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/include/c++/10.2.0/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /opt/cross/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/include/c++/10.2.0/ios:42,
                 from /opt/cross/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/include/c++/10.2.0/ostream:38,
                 from /opt/cross/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/include/c++/10.2.0/iostream:39,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/opt/cross/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/include/c++/10.2.0/ext/string_conversions.h: In destructor '__gnu_cxx::__stoa(_TRet (*)(const _CharT*, _CharT**, _Base ...), const char*, const _CharT*, std::size_t*, _Base ...)::_Save_errno::~_Save_errno()':
/opt/cross/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/include/c++/10.2.0/ext/string_conversions.h:64:23: error: 'errno' was not declared in this scope
   64 |  ~_Save_errno() { if (errno == 0) errno = _M_errno; }
      |                       ^~~~~
/opt/cross/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/include/c++/10.2.0/ext/string_conversions.h:64:23: note: 'errno' is defined in header '<cerrno>'; did you forget to '#include <cerrno>'?
/opt/cross/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/include/c++/10.2.0/ext/string_conversions.h: In function '_Ret __gnu_cxx::__stoa(_TRet (*)(const _CharT*, _CharT**, _Base ...), const char*, const _CharT*, std::size_t*, _Base ...)':
/opt/cross/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/include/c++/10.2.0/ext/string_conversions.h:84:16: error: 'errno' was not declared in this scope
   84 |       else if (errno == ERANGE
      |                ^~~~~
/opt/cross/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/include/c++/10.2.0/ext/string_conversions.h:84:16: note: 'errno' is defined in header '<cerrno>'; did you forget to '#include <cerrno>'?
In file included from /opt/cross/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/include/c++/10.2.0/system_error:39,
                 from /opt/cross/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/include/c++/10.2.0/bits/ios_base.h:46,
                 from /opt/cross/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/include/c++/10.2.0/ios:42,
                 from /opt/cross/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/include/c++/10.2.0/ostream:38,
                 from /opt/cross/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/include/c++/10.2.0/iostream:39,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/opt/cross/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/include/c++/10.2.0/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bits/error_constants.h: At global scope:
/opt/cross/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/include/c++/10.2.0/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bits/error_constants.h:122:27: error: 'ENOTSUP' was not declared in this scope
  122 |       not_supported =     ENOTSUP,
      |
```

**UPD: WSL and virtual machines are not an option in my case**

Comment: do you really need cygwin? windows subsytem for linux is the easier approach these days

Comment: @AlanBirtles, yes I need cygwin, WSL is not an option in my case, either I can't rely on virtual machines.

Comment: Can you run with -H and verify that no native cygwin includes are being used?

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. run with -H produces a huge amount of text that I can't paste here. I've checked the output and I do not see any pure cygwin related includes, everything is taken from cross-compiler's directory.

Comment: then I don't know, this could be a cross compiler build issue, the instructions are from 2014, who knows what has changed.

Comment: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/CPU_SET.3.html are you using `#define _GNU_SOURCE ` and do you have the proper `<sched.h>` ?

Comment: @matzeri adding _GNU_SOURCE doesn't help. The same set of errors.
How I can check if used sched.h is proper?

Comment: the definition of `cpu_set_t` should be there in the Linux header, if I am not wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to solve the issue.

The problem was in the sys-include directory 
`opt/cross/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/sys-include`

This directory has include files with the same names as the ones from
`opt/cross/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/include`
but with different content.

The `sys-include` directory was searched by the compiler before the regular `include`.

Renaming or removing `sys-include` solves the issue and code can be compiled.

I don't know the purpose of the `sys-include` directory, when it was created and why the duplicated files in this directory have another content.

Accepting my own post as answer to indicate that the issue can be solved.